# Windows XP Virtual Machine Shortcomings for Developer Environment

Tags: windows-7, windows-xp, virtual-machine

A couple of old SDK's are only supported for Win XP x32 - I am wondering what sort of shortcomings would I encounter if i used a virtual XP x32 on 7 x64, rather than native Win XP x32?

Answer (score 1):

Its mainly performance issues (and mainly compiling tasks) that would be shortcommings, but everything else is fine